# making a "compiler"/binary editor to modify my .net application

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, binary

This is what I'm trying to accomplish:

I have two applications. One is a client application the other one would be a compiler. Client uses encryption and for safety reasons I would like the users to be able to run the 'compiler' application, that would hard code a security key inside already compiled binary, so each client has its own encryption key stored inside of it. Is this even possible or the solution would be crazy? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure all you are talking about is rewritting the MSIL code.  Microsoft does this all the time with code contracts.  Here is a link to an article explaining how: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188743.aspx

Another example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20565/Assembly-Manipulation-and-C-VB-NET-Code-Injection

Answer (score 1):

If your assembly is strongly signed, you cannot modify it. You cannot save back a modified .net assembly to disk. However, you can build your assemble ( As Kevin stated) to be able to modify the code loaded in memory at runtime. It will not affect the image on the disk and the modification will be run at every time the application is started.

Comment: Thanks! What do you mean by "It will not affect the image on the disk"? The changes will not be saved in binary?

Comment: Exactly. It will modify code as it is loaded, but you will not be able to save it on the disk.